# PDFTron WebViewer - CORS error on trying to display XOD file stored in Azure BLOB storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage, pdftron

I am using WebViewer 2.2.2 and trying to show on an ASP.NET MVC 5 view an XOD file stored in Azure Blob storage, url as : https://somename.blob.core.windows.net/containername/GettingsStarted.xod

I get a CORS error in browser console as "**CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request.**"

I found the URL https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/tutorials/xdomain.html to enable CORS. What URL should I provide in proxy.html file as every XOD blob stored in Azure BLOB storage would have a differenert URL.

The portion https://somename.blob.core.windows.net/containername/ would be same but the filename would be different for dirrerent XOD's. So, how can I pass the XOD filename in the proxy.html file?

Is this the correct way to handle the CORS issue https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/tutorials/xdomain.html or is there another simpler way?

```
    @model XODViewer.DataModel.Document

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Document";
    }

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/lib/WebViewer.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #viewer {
            width: 1024px;
            height: 600px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(function () {
                var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
                var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
                    path: 'lib',
                    type: 'html5',
                    documentType: "xod",
 initialDoc:"https://somename.blob.core.windows.net/containername/GettingsStarted.xod",
                    config: '../../lib/WebViewerConfig.js',
                    streaming: true,
                    enableAnnotations: false,
                    enableOfflineMode: false,
                    enableReadOnlyMode: true,
                    azureWorkaround: true
                }, viewerElement);
            });
    </script>

    <div id="viewer"class="xod-viewer-div">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I followed this [tutorial](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/tutorials/getting-started.html) to get started with WebViewer. I could encounter the same error as you mentioned as follows:

```html
<script>
    $(function() {
        var viewerElement = document.getElementById("viewer");
        var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
            path: "/libs",
            type: "html5",
            documentType:'xod',
            initialDoc:"https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/docs/GettingStarted.xod"
        }, viewerElement);
    });
</script>
```

[image]

For cross domain accessing, you could leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to configure CORS Setting as follows:

[image]

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Comment: MaxAgeInSeconds definition states "This defines the maximum number of seconds browser will cache the pre-flight request. Since this “pre-flight” requests are billable, it is generally recommended that you set this value to a higher number so that browser does not make this “pre-flight” request frequently". (1) Is it ok to leave this to a value of 100 or maybe even change to 50 as I believe that once the XOD is downloaded in WebViewer there is no request made by browser again (2) Is it safe to make the same setting in PROD Azure instance (3)   Any PowerShell cmdlet example

Comment: (1) For MaxAgeInSeconds you could change to 50 as you expected. (2) The container access level is read only, for a more safe way, you could add a CORS rule for the specific origin. (3) You could refer to this [sample](https://gist.github.com/irwinwilliams/4cf93b6e2461c753ff125590650186ae).